# how to upload video to remote MySQL server using WP7 application using php backend?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to upload video to remote MySQL database using WebClient using PHP as back-end, but to do so I need to convert it to binary string and i don't know how to do the same. Please help me out.

Would be really grateful for any helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

See whether this alternate soln can be useful to you. You can upload the data using multipart httpwebrequest and you can send the byte array of the video